# componentWillReceiveProps is getting previous props - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing a **state** as **props** in child component, but child is updating previous props to its state.

For example:

I am passing **state = a**, then state is updated to **state = b**. Child will update it as **a**.

Parent:

```
<div className="custom-container">
    {console.log("Passing Tab:"+this.state.selectedTab)}
    <Companyprofilehead data={companyData} selfprofile={false} tab={this.state.selectedTab}/>
</div>
```

In above code's console.log will give output:

```
Passing Tab: b
```

In Child's componentWillMount():

```
componentWillMount(){
    var currentTab = this.props.tab;
    console.log("CURRENT TAB:"+currentTab);
    this.setState({
      currentTab: currentTab
    })
}
```

And child's **componentWillReceiveProps()**:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
 var currentTab = this.props.tab;
  console.log("CURRENT TAB IN WILL PROPS:"+currentTab);
  this.setState({
    currentTab: currentTab
  })
}
```

Above code will display output as:

```
CURRENT TAB IN WILL PROPS: a
```

If in parent's `Passing Tab: a` then

in child's `CURRENT TAB IN WILL PROPS: b`

It is being vise versa, What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new props will be in variable newProps. So you have to use `newProps.tab` to get the incoming prop.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  const currentTab = newProps.tab;
  console.log("CURRENT TAB IN WILL PROPS:"+currentTab);
  this.setState({
    currentTab: currentTab
  })
}
```

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Great, thanks it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Inside `componentWIllRecieveProps` pass `newProps.tab` `instead of this.props.tab`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
 var currentTab = newProps.tab;
}
```